# Bootstrap navbar dropdown in Angularjs doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The function I uses of bootstrap navbar dropdown doesn't work.
[My html code](http://plnkr.co/edit/YiWvPxV85AqRSj8Wz9b5?p=preview)

It runs correctly on plunker.
But when I run the same code.
My running page becomes as follow:

[image: enter image description]

When I click the Dropdown link, browser direct to "example.com"

This is my dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.0",

"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

Can anyone can help me to figure it out?
Thank you!

Comment: Remove the `href="http://example.com"` link or change it to `#`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing you need to change.

1. In the `HTML` page, replace the href="http://example.com" with href="#".
2. You missed `bootstrap.min.js`. Add the script `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

I tested in my local, mostly the issue is missing of `bootstrap.min.js` (bootstrap library file).

Comment: Follow your first suggestion, I change the href. But bootstrap.min.js has already added to my file. After I replace "example.com" with "#", it still has the same problem.

Comment: Not yet, the problem still comes out.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap.min.js is loaded. I used Starter template code from https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/.